# Javascript / Jquery Validation on required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework-2.0

I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer for my question.
Firstly, i would like to have a submit button which will be disable if all the required fields are not filled.
I found some example if all the fields are filled but i have required and not required ones So,
I need to find if the required ones are filled or not.
I am currently out of ideas of how to make it happen.
Just in case , i am using play framework 2.1.x with Scala.

Cheers,
Ilgün

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var submitButton = $("#myForm input[type='submit']");
    $("#myForm input.required").change(function () {
        var valid = true;
        $.each($("#myForm input.required"), function (index, value) {
            alert("comes here");
            if(!$(value).val()){
               valid = false;
            }
        });
        if(valid){
            $(submitButton).attr("disabled", false);
            console.log("valid");
            alert("valid");
        } 
        else{
             $(submitButton).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

My submit Button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" id="form-submit" onclick="return myConfirm();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

First you can identify the required fields with a class of required:

```
<form id="myForm">
    *<input type="text" class="required" /></br>
    *<input type="text" class="required" /></br>
    <input type="text" /></br>
    <input type="text" /></br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Initially disable your submit button:

```
var submitButton = $("#myForm input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
```

Then use jQuery to loop through your inputs everytime one changes, and check if there are values in them. If they all have a value then enable the submit button, if not disable it:

```
    $("#myForm input.required").change(function () {
        var valid = true;
        $.each($("#myForm input.required"), function (index, value) {
            if(!$(value).val()){
               valid = false;
            }
        });
        if(valid){
            $(submitButton).attr("disabled", false);
        } 
        else{
            $(submitButton).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/4puBy/) with a simple example of what you are describing using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some basic stuff with plain HTML/JS to show a possible way of input validation:

HTML:

```
    <html>
      <form id="form">
        <input class="form-input" data-required="true" type="text" />
        <input class="form-input" data-required="true" type="text" />

        <input class="form-input" data-required="false" type="text" /> 
        <input class="form-input" data-required="false" type="text" />

        <input id="form-submit" type="submit" disabled />
      </form>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // on input change:
      $(".form-input").on('change', function() {
        // hide the input (not neccessary)
        $("#form-submit").hide();
        // enable it
        $("#form-submit").removeProp("disabled");

        // check all inputs
        $.each(".form-input", function() {
          // read element values
          var required = $(this).data("required");
          var empty = ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null)
          // if element is required but empty:
          if (required && empty) {
            // disable submit button
            $("#form-submit").prop("disabled", "disabled");
          }
        }          

        // now the submit button is enabled if all required inputs are filled
        // and it is disabled if at least one required input is empty

        // after hiding it: make the button visible again (not neccessary)
        $("#form-submit").show();
      }
    });
```